# how to get selected tableview button value while search in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

**how to get selected tableview button value while search in iOS**

I'm having 1 button inside tableviewcell and in that button i retrieve json
value and stored in it,but when i clicked on that button i get that button value correct. But when i search in tableview and click on that button i will get a wrong value in iOS.

```
view *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.manid = [[man objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]objectForKey:@"mgrid"];
```

i am using this to get selected button value

```
cell.invi.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"mgrid"];
cell.invi.tag = indexPath.row;
```

this is my tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: can you show that search and button click methods

Comment: And `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, too, where you must be setting the `tag`.

Comment: Not sure if you are still waiting for an answer, but this one might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985435/clicking-button-within-uitableview-cell-gives-wrong-result-while-search/44985566#44985566