# clicking button within UITableview cell gives wrong result while search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Within the cells of a tableview I have a button. The button basically opens the file that the cell refers to. This is working fine while the search is not on. But while the search is on, I can't seem to get the correct row within the search results array.
This is what I have tried so far:
in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I tagged the button.

```
myDownloadsBtn = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:106];
```

the action is set as follows:

```
[myDownloadsBtn addTarget:self action: @selector(downloadClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then in downloadClicked I have the following

```
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSString *todoRow;
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self->tableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self->tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
```

but it gives me the indexPath of the VISIBLE current position, not the position of the row within the search results array.

Also, my delegate method ofdidSelectRowAtIndexPath works fine with and without the search. It is just for buttons within the cells.

I have found this question, but there is no answer:
[how to get selected tableview button value while search in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537492/how-to-get-selected-tableview-button-value-while-search-in-ios).

the other questions deal with how to know the actual cell selected when searching, but that is not my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can assign tag to button as

```
[myDownloadsBtn setTag:indexPath.row];
```

and in your downloadClicked action access the tag hence the index of the row that is being touched / button clicked

```
-(IBAction)myDownloadsBtn:(id)sender
 {
   UIButton *tappedBtn = (UIButton*)sender;
   Nslog("%d",tappedBtn.tag); // Get tag hence indexpath of tableview in which button is clicked. 
  }
```

**You need to reload  table data with search results array.**

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: thank you!! Apologies for replying so late, but this is just perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

For the identification of object on particular index of `tebleview` you need to give your particular `indexpath.row` as tag to your `UIButton`.

Here is the best approch for that.

```
aCell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row

[aCell.yourButton addTarget:self action: @selector(downloadClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

After that you need to handle this event

```
-(IBAction)myDownloadsBtn:(id)sender
 {
   UIButton *tappedBtn = (UIButton*)sender;
   Nslog("%d",tappedBtn.tag); // it gives index of object related to your cell
 }
```

but what you said is you are not getting the right result after performing the search.
What i am thinking is after getting the result from search you need to reload your `tableview` using

```
[yourTableView reloadData]
```

Comment: thank you so much! I am getting the right search results. The issue is when pressing a button within the search results array. Tagging is the right thing. I get an error when I put 'cell.myDownloadsBtn.tag = indexpath.row'. It works if it just myDownloadsBtn.tag.